# Button onClickListener on AlertBuilder not working

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity and a layout to call in AlertBuilder, 
I have 3 buttons in layout and some code for each one.
The problem is that when I create and show alert, onClickListener not working

I don't want use alert buttons and have to use my buttons on layout

**MainActivity Code (Call Alert)**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (MainActivity.this).getLayoutInflater();
builder.setTitle("Login Form");

builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_prompt, null));
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

**LoginPromptActivity**

```
public class LoginPromptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_prompt);
    Button bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginPromptActivity.this, "Button Clicked",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
}
```

**Layout XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".LoginPromptActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login_prompt">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="147dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:text="Username"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:text="Password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUserName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Register"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Exit App"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnRegister"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPassword" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't get it with this code. Are you trying to use the same layout both for alertdialog and the activity layout?

Answer (score 2):

I have read your question and I think you have face some problem to implement onclick listener
on alert dialog buttons. if we have use any custom layout for alert dialog so do not need any activity  to handle this layout. According to your code sinppet you have create a alert dialog using custom layout and use a activity to handle this layout button click

Try this this code create custom alert dialog , and handle its click listener

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Login Form");
    View view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);

    alertDialogBuilder.create();
     //alert dialog button 
    TextView ok_btn=view.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
    //buttton click
   ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast
               .makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
               .show();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void showAlertDialog(){
@SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View promptView = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.enter_pin_dialog, null);    

 Button accept= (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.accept_btn);
    Button deny= (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.deny_btn);    

 deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // do what you want
        }
    });    

accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // do what you want
        }
    });    


 NotificationUtil.messageDialog(
            mainActivity,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            false,
            true,
            promptView,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );}    

public class NotificationUtil {

private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static AlertDialog cancelDialog;
private static AlertDialog messageDialog;
private static Vector<AlertDialog> dialogs= new Vector<AlertDialog>();

public static void messageDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Integer iconResId,
                                 boolean cancelable, boolean openKeyboard, View view,
                                 String positiveStr, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener,
                                 String negativeStr, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeListener,
                                 DialogInterface.OnShowListener showListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener dismissListener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(cancelable);

    if (iconResId != null) {
        builder.setIcon(iconResId);
    }

    if (view != null) {
        builder.setView(view);
    }

    if (positiveStr != null) {
        builder.setPositiveButton(positiveStr, positiveListener);
    }

    if (negativeStr != null) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeStr, negativeListener);
    }

    messageDialog = builder.create();
    dialogs.add(messageDialog);

    if (openKeyboard) {
        Window window = messageDialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    if (showListener != null) {
        messageDialog.setOnShowListener(showListener);
    }

    if (dismissListener != null) {
        messageDialog.setOnDismissListener(dismissListener);
    }


    messageDialog.show();

    ScrollView buttonsContainer = (ScrollView) messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);
    if (buttonsContainer != null) {
        List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
            views.add(buttonsContainer.getChildAt(i));
        }
        buttonsContainer.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = views.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            buttonsContainer.addView(views.get(i));
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
            alertbox.setMessage("ddddd");
            alertbox.setTitle("dddd");
            alertbox.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_del);

            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                            int arg1) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {

                }
            });
            alertbox.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Open your MainActivity.java and add OnClickListener to your button to create an alert dialog :**

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create a Custom Alert Dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Dismiss the dialog here
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Add ok operation here
                }
            });

            builder.show();


        }
    });
```

You can also add custom buttons to your alert dialog.